# Archimedean Property Proof

Tags: real-analysis

$\forall a > 0, a\in\mathbb R, \forall b\in\mathbb R, \exists p\in\mathbb N, pa > b$.

I know the intuition makes sense, and the proof should be simple, but don't know how to do it.

Comment: That will depend a great deal on what properties of $\Bbb R$ and $\Bbb N$ you’re allowed to assume.

Answer (score 1):

It will depend on what tools you have at your disposal. I believe any simple solution will hinge on proving that $\forall x \in \mathbb{R}$, $\exists p \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $x<p$ (that is, the natural numbers are unbounded). Apply this fact when $x=\frac{b}{a}$.

Proving that the natural numbers are unbounded is the part that will depend on the tools you have. Maybe you already have this fact, or maybe you'll have to construct a natural number greater than $x$ yourself.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose otherwise, that $\forall p\in\mathbb N$, $b\ge pa$. Then since $S=\{pa:p\in\mathbb N\}\subseteq \mathbb R$ is a bounded set (by $b$), it must have a [least upper bound](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Least-upper-bound_property#Statement_of_the_property), which we call $U$. However, I claim $U-a<U$ will also be an upper bound, which contradicts the minimality of $U$.

To prove this, let $pa\in S$ be arbitrary. Then $(p+1)a\in S$, so $(p+1)a\le U$. But this means $pa\le U-a$, which is a contradiction since $p$ was arbitrary.